# How to understand what z3 is doing when it loops?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I'm having trouble figuring out how to debug z3. Is there a way to see what the SMT engine is "trying" to make it easier to understand why it's failing to see a solution that seems obvious and where it's devoting it's time instead?

As an example in my particular circumstance, I'm working with a recursive function and setting z3 to find inputs where the function has a certain result. SMT was timing out, yadda yadda yadda, turns out the thing I was recursing on had a base case of 0, but if it ever went negative, it'd recurse forever. Z3 didn't know not to pick a negative number, so it'd get stuck. I figured that out by staring at the code, but if I had some output somewhere that said "trying i == -10, trying i == -11, etc" it'd be very obvious what was going wrong.

I'm continuing to have less obvious issues, and I suspect Z3 is still getting stuck in loops. How can I see the loop it's getting stuck in?

Comment: z3 doesn't really "execute" your functions, so strictly speaking _stuck in a loop_ doesn't mean anything in the context of an SMT solver. What's most likely happening was probably the E-matching engine kept on producing non-productive instantiations. Having said that, you can always turn verbose mode on via `z3 -v:10` etc., and have it print a trace of what it's doing. What it prints, however, may not be what you expect to see; though can still be useful.

Comment: This shows me things like `(smt.recfun :increase-depth 19)...(smt.simplifier-done)(smt.searching)`, but that doesn't really give me any information about what's being instantiated.

Comment: Hence my previous comment: "What it prints, however, may not be what you expect to see; though can still be useful."

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately very difficult to find out *why exactly* Z3 is running forever, but typical culprits are matching loops due to bad patterns (a quantifier instantiations yields new ground terms that trigger another instantiations, and so on) and non-linear arithmetic.

The [Z3 axiom profiler](https://bitbucket.org/viperproject/axiom-profiler/src/default/), described in [this paper](http://pm.inf.ethz.ch/publications/getpdf.php?bibname=Own&id=BeckerMuellerSummers19.pdf) can help with identifying problems due to too many quantifier instantiations.